# how to set spaces in strings

Tags: python, string, user-input

I am trying to have the program check the user input for "get up" or "rise and shine" then have it print "im up". The problem is it won't print "im up" it goes straight to the else statement. This code i have right now makes it where if i were to change "get up" to "hello" then if i were to enter anything in the input and included "hello" in the input it will then print "test" and i would like to keep it that way if it is possible?  code:

```
dic = {"get,up", "rise,and,shine"}
test = raw_input("test: ")
tokens = test.split()
if dic.intersection(tokens):
    print "test"
else:
    print "?"
```

help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`dic.intersection()` returns the intersection of two sets. For example:

```
{1, 2, 3}.intersection({2, 3, 4})  # {2, 3}
```

You probably just want to test for membership instead:

```
if tokens in dic:
    ...
```

Although that won't work either, as you're splitting up the string by spaces, which will make it test for the individual words, not the whole phrase. Also, naming your set `dic` isn't a good idea. It's a set, not a dictionary.

In short, don't use sets and don't use `.split()`:

```
phrases = ['get up', 'rise and shine']
phrase = raw_input('Enter a phrase: ')

if phrase in phrases:
    print "test"
else:
    print "?"
```

Comment: The thing is with this code if i were to enter "hello get up" it will not print test it will go to the else statement.

Comment: @user2458048: Would you want a match if the user typed 'up you get'?  That has the two words 'get' and 'up' in it, but not in the same order.  Also, do you simply want at least one of the words in the phrase (such as 'get up') to appear in the input, or do you need every one of the words in the phrase to appear in the input?  The intersection method would return a true value if at least one word appears.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: is there a way to get the two words is the correct order for example someone enters "can you please get up"? it looks for the most important words which are 'get up' and sees that they are in the correct order then prints "im up"?

Comment: @user2458048: I'm sure there is, but my knowledge of Python is limited.  For your requirement, neither a set nor a frozenset is appropriate; sets don't preserve order.  You'd probably need to store the phrases to be searched for as lists of words, and the input likewise, and you'd have to check not only that each word in the phrase appears in the input, but also that the second word appears after the first.